# Hibernate: InvalidMappingException

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

I'm using hibernate framework for a desktop application (Swing) and I called the needed librairies for hibernte to work but I still get this exception when I create a `SessionFactory`:

```
private static SessionFactory factory = new Configuration(). configure(). buildSessionFactory();
```

[image]

And this is the list of used librairies:
[image]

My config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
         </property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            org.postgresql.Driver
         </property>

         <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_hibernate
         </property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            postgres
         </property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            root
         </property>

         <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Employee" table="employee">
     <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the employee detail.
     </meta>
     <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
     <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
     <property name="salary" column="salary" type="double"/>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing encoding part from top level tag in both config and hbm file.

I am not sure if this will work for you, it worked for us.